# What is a common pattern on highlighting in ebooks

Tags: usability

There seem to be coming out new ebook readers and application for a digital reading experience everyday.

Now my question is what is a common pattern on highlighting in ebooks. And how can it be explained?

Comment: as in how do you show highlighting in books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the standard highlighting process used generally by shading the text using  a highlighter. Do note that users will be using their fingers to most likely mark as passage of text so you will need to provide an option to allow the user to select when he wants to highlight something as opposed to when he is just tapping on the screen.

Here is an example of how kindle does this

[image]

iBooks allows users to choose the highlight color along with other options on tapping on the screen as shown below

[image]